# Link between Tensor Operations and Differential Forms

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

On Pg 101 of MTW Gravitation, I came across the expression:
$$\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{u})=\langle F,u\rangle \tag{1}$$
where $\bf{u}$ is the 4-velocity of the test charged particle, the $\bf{F}$ on the LHS is the EM field strength tensor, and that on the RHS is the electromagnetic 2-form, the $\bf{Faraday}$, defined as 
$$\mathbf{F}=\frac{1}{2}F_{\alpha \beta}\, \mathbf{d}x^{\alpha} \wedge \mathbf{d}x^{\beta} \tag{2}$$
where $\bf{d}$ is the exterior derivative.
But I do not see how the relation in (1) holds.

I wrote (1) in the components form:
$$F_{\alpha \beta} u^{\beta}=\frac{1}{2}F_{\alpha \beta}u^{\gamma}\, \langle\mathbf{d}x^{\alpha} \wedge \mathbf{d}x^{\beta}, \mathbf{e}_{\gamma}\rangle \tag{3}$$

What properties of the inner product (and perhaps the wedge product) would allow me to remove that factor of $1/2$ and inner product so that $(1)$ can hold?

Is there any possible relation to
$$\langle\mathbf{d}x^{i_1} \wedge...\wedge \mathbf{d}x^{i_p}, \mathbf{e}_{j_1} \wedge \dotsb \wedge \mathbf{e}_{j_p}\rangle=\delta^{i_1...i_p}_{j_1...j_p} \tag{4}$$

Comment: Write out the entries for equation $(2)$ noting $dx^{\alpha} \wedge dx^{\beta} =  -dx^{\beta} \wedge dx^{\alpha}$. For instance, in $F_{\alpha\beta}$ , there is a $E$ entry and a $-E$ entry, so the number of wedge product terms should be shorter by a factor of $2.$ It's the same information only a shorter way writing it.

Comment: And incidently, regarding the inner product, use $dx^{\alpha} \wedge dx^{\beta} =  dx^{\alpha} \otimes dx^{\beta}-dx^{\beta} \otimes dx^{\alpha}$ i.e.,  $\langle dx^{\alpha} \wedge dx^{\beta},u^{\gamma}e_{\gamma}\rangle =  dx^{\alpha} \langle dx^{\beta},u^{\gamma}e_{\gamma} \rangle -dx^{\beta}\langle dx^{\alpha} ,u^{\gamma}e_{\gamma}\rangle$.

Comment: @ Cinaed Simson Does that imply $<dx^{\alpha} \otimes dx^{\beta}, u>=dx^{\alpha}<dx^{\beta}, u>$ then? What property of the tensor product allows this for is just because of the definition of the inner product?

Comment: It looks like my previous comment may have been mangled - it should have been: $$dx^{\alpha} \wedge dx^{\beta} =  dx^{\alpha} \otimes dx^{\beta}-dx^{\beta} \otimes dx^{\alpha}.$$ And yes, it's the inner product - or contraction of a $1$-form -  or a co-vector - with a vector - or a sum of over an "up" and a "down" index. In your case, $\gamma$ has to equal $\beta$: $dx^{\alpha}\langle dx^{\beta},u^{\beta}e_{\beta} \rangle =dx^{\alpha}u^{\beta}\langle dx^{\beta},e_{\beta} \rangle$